# Matlab Equivalent of sortrows for columns

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

To sort a matrix according to all columns except the first, I used the following code. I do not want sortrows to consider the first column because that is meant to keep track of the row numbers.

```
B = [1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     2     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     3     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     0
     4     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
     5     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
     6     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
     7     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     8     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0]; 

D = -sortrows(-B,[2:size(B,2)])
```

What if you want to sort the matrix according to all rows except the first, so the first element of each column would be ignored when sorting them in descending order? Is there any similar function to sortrows?

To clarify, the desired output is

```
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
 2     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 3     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
 4     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 5     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
 6     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 7     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
 8     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: Transpose, `sortrows`, transpose back?

Comment: @beaker Hm... what mismatch do you see?

Comment: OP, it would be helpful if you showed the desired output from your sample input.

Comment: @beaker I understand the question text as wanting to sort columns, considered as atoms, according to rows (like `sortrows` sort rows according to columns). But yes, clarification is needed

Comment: Tangential to the question, but worth noting you can just get the 2nd output of `sortrows`, i.e. `[data,idx] = sortrows(data)` to keep track of the sort index, instead of faffing around with additional rows/columns in your matrix.

Comment: I added the desired output. The order of the third to last and 2nd last columns is interchangeable.

Comment: Okay, I was *way* off ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via

- transposing the input and output
- keeping column 1 separate
- you can use negative sort indices to avoid what you've done making the input and output negative

```
A = [B(:,1) sortrows( B(:,2:end).', -(2:size(B,1)) ).'];

>> A 
A =
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
     2     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     3     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     4     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     5     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     6     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     7     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
     8     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
```